# Syntax for image button

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

How do I make the image button change to different fragment on click?

On the homepage fragment I have an image button. How do I code it so that it changes to a different fragment when clicked. Note that I have java classes for all my fragments as well as the main activity class.

Where would I put the code for this image button and how would I do it because everything I have tried doesn't work.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do u want to change your fragment when the image button is clicked or do u want to change image button drawable for each fragment?

Comment: Post which you tried for it

Comment: @JerinAMathews i want to change the fragment

Comment: ImageButton doesn't matter. How would you change fragments at all? Please [edit] with what "doesn't work"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create onClickListener for the image button in home fragment and inside onclick:

```
 Fragment fragment = new {your-fragment()};
 FragmentManager fm1 = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
 FragmentTransaction ft1 = fm1.beginTransaction();
 fm1.popBackStack();
 ft1.replace({layout}, fragment).addToBackStack("tag");
 ft1.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
 ft1.commit();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: would i put this in the main activity class or inside the fragment java class?

Comment: Where ever u want. This code is to change fragment from another fragment. If u want to change fragment from ur mainactivity use this code there by replacing `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();` with just `getSupportFragmentManager();`